# CSS priority messed up

Tags: css

For proper CSS priority setting, I searched around a bit and found nothing similar of sort. I vaguely remember someone posting about CSS priority in the comments,a long time ago, but I do not recall at all. Hence, I'm asking this question - for one part, to get my answer - and to archive this answer for future reference for others(also inclusive of myself incase this happens again).

### Here's my snippet:

```css
.ContainerTitle {
  background: #fff;
  float: left;
  padding: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  border: solid 1px #000;
  font-size: Large;
  color: #000;
  text-align: left;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all .1s ease-out;
}
.DownloadThis,
.ViewThis {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border: solid 1px #fff;
  width: 40px;
}
/*PROBLEM BELOW HERE HELP!!! */

.showHint {
  margin-top: 20px;
  background: #f1f1f1;
}
.ViewThis:hover .showHint:after {
  content: '*Hint: View Online';
}
.DownloadThis:hover .showHint:after {
  content: '*Hint: Download';
}
/*PROBLEM ABOVE HERE HELP!!! */

.DownloadThis {
  background: #1D9C73;
  color: #fff;
}
.ViewThis {
  background: #7D529E;
  color: #fff;
}
.DownloadThis:hover,
.ViewThis:hover {
  border: solid 1px #000;
  background: #fff;
}
.DownloadThis:hover {
  color: #1D9C73;
}
.ViewThis:hover {
  color: #7D529E;
}
.ContainerTitle:before,
.DownloadThis:before,
.ViewThis:before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-decoration: inherit;
  padding-left: 6px;
  padding-right: 8px;
  font-size: 32px;
}
.ContainerTitle:before {
  content: '\f0f6';
  font-size: 24px;
}
.DownloadThis:before {
  content: '\f019';
}
.ViewThis:before {
  content: '\f06e';
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="ContainerTitle">SYLLABUS:
  <div class="DownloadThis"></div>
  <div class="ViewThis"></div>
  <div class="showHint"></div>
</div>
<div class="ContainerTitle">NOTE:
  <div class="DownloadThis"></div>
  <div class="ViewThis"></div>
  <p class="showHint"></p>
</div>
```

I want to show Hint with the help of showHint class when I hover over the desired classes with this code

```
.ViewThis:hover .showHint:after{content:'*Hint: View Online';}
.DownloadThis:hover .showHint:after{content:'*Hint: Download';}
```

but, for some reason, it is **not working!**

> I assume it is because I messed up the priority in CSS setting.

---

---

I want it to achieve an effect similar to this(but while hovering over **.DownloadThis** and **.ViewThis .** *If a **different generic message** appears when I hover over **.ContainerTitle** that'd be awesome too!*):

```css
.ContainerTitle {
  background: #fff;
  float: left;
  padding: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  border: solid 1px #000;
  font-size: Large;
  color: #000;
  text-align: left;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all .1s ease-out;
}
.DownloadThis,
.ViewThis {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border: solid 1px #fff;
  width: 40px;
}
.showHint {
  margin-top: 20px;
  background: #f1f1f1;
}
.ContainerTitle:hover .showHint:after {
  content: '*Hint: I want to display text like this!';
}
.DownloadThis {
  background: #1D9C73;
  color: #fff;
}
.ViewThis {
  background: #7D529E;
  color: #fff;
}
.DownloadThis:hover,
.ViewThis:hover {
  border: solid 1px #000;
  background: #fff;
}
.DownloadThis:hover {
  color: #1D9C73;
}
.ViewThis:hover {
  color: #7D529E;
}
.ContainerTitle:before,
.DownloadThis:before,
.ViewThis:before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-decoration: inherit;
  padding-left: 6px;
  padding-right: 8px;
  font-size: 32px;
}
.ContainerTitle:before {
  content: '\f0f6';
  font-size: 24px;
}
.DownloadThis:before {
  content: '\f019';
}
.ViewThis:before {
  content: '\f06e';
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="ContainerTitle">SYLLABUS:
  <div class="DownloadThis"></div>
  <div class="ViewThis"></div>
  <div class="showHint"></div>
</div>
<div class="ContainerTitle">NOTE:
  <div class="DownloadThis"></div>
  <div class="ViewThis"></div>
  <p class="showHint"></p>
</div>
```

> **Also, I would like to know why the hover on .ContainerTitle would work while it fails to work on .DownloadThis and .ViewThis ?**
>   Is the answer related to the fact that both .DownloadThis and .ViewThis are chid of .ContainerTitle? If so how does this type of relation affect containers? I request this information so that I will not repeat the same mistake in the future.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't working because `.showHint` is not a descendant of `.ViewThis`. You need to use the [general sibling selector (`~`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors):

```
.ViewThis:hover ~ .showHint:after{content:'*Hint: View Online';}
.DownloadThis:hover ~ .showHint:after{content:'*Hint: Download';}
```

Example:

```css
.ContainerTitle {
  background: #fff;
  float: left;
  padding: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  border: solid 1px #000;
  font-size: Large;
  color: #000;
  text-align: left;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all .1s ease-out;
}
.DownloadThis,
.ViewThis {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border: solid 1px #fff;
  width: 40px;
}
/*PROBLEM BELOW HERE HELP!!! */

.showHint {
  margin-top: 20px;
  background: #f1f1f1;
}
.ViewThis:hover ~ .showHint:after {
  content: '*Hint: View Online';
}
.DownloadThis:hover ~ .showHint:after {
  content: '*Hint: Download';
}
/*PROBLEM ABOVE HERE HELP!!! */

.DownloadThis {
  background: #1D9C73;
  color: #fff;
}
.ViewThis {
  background: #7D529E;
  color: #fff;
}
.DownloadThis:hover,
.ViewThis:hover {
  border: solid 1px #000;
  background: #fff;
}
.DownloadThis:hover {
  color: #1D9C73;
}
.ViewThis:hover {
  color: #7D529E;
}
.ContainerTitle:before,
.DownloadThis:before,
.ViewThis:before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-decoration: inherit;
  padding-left: 6px;
  padding-right: 8px;
  font-size: 32px;
}
.ContainerTitle:before {
  content: '\f0f6';
  font-size: 24px;
}
.DownloadThis:before {
  content: '\f019';
}
.ViewThis:before {
  content: '\f06e';
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="ContainerTitle">SYLLABUS:
  <div class="DownloadThis"></div>
  <div class="ViewThis"></div>
  <div class="showHint"></div>
</div>
<div class="ContainerTitle">NOTE:
  <div class="DownloadThis"></div>
  <div class="ViewThis"></div>
  <p class="showHint"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: This won't work for `.DownloadThis`, it will only work for `.ViewThis`.

Comment: Yes I've just realised you have two different elements. See update

Comment: Yeah I noticed, I was just a bit too quick

Answer (score 1):

You need the next sibling and general sibling selector for this. Read about it [here](https://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/#article-header-id-2).

```css
.ContainerTitle {
  background: #fff;
  float: left;
  padding: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  border: solid 1px #000;
  font-size: Large;
  color: #000;
  text-align: left;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all .1s ease-out;
}
.DownloadThis,
.ViewThis {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border: solid 1px #fff;
  width: 40px;
}
/*PROBLEM BELOW HERE HELP!!! */

.showHint {
  margin-top: 20px;
  background: #f1f1f1;
}
.ViewThis:hover + .showHint:after {
  content: '*Hint: View Online';
}
.DownloadThis:hover ~ .showHint:after {
  content: '*Hint: Download';
}
/*PROBLEM ABOVE HERE HELP!!! */

.DownloadThis {
  background: #1D9C73;
  color: #fff;
}
.ViewThis {
  background: #7D529E;
  color: #fff;
}
.DownloadThis:hover,
.ViewThis:hover {
  border: solid 1px #000;
  background: #fff;
}
.DownloadThis:hover {
  color: #1D9C73;
}
.ViewThis:hover {
  color: #7D529E;
}
.ContainerTitle:before,
.DownloadThis:before,
.ViewThis:before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-decoration: inherit;
  padding-left: 6px;
  padding-right: 8px;
  font-size: 32px;
}
.ContainerTitle:before {
  content: '\f0f6';
  font-size: 24px;
}
.DownloadThis:before {
  content: '\f019';
}
.ViewThis:before {
  content: '\f06e';
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="ContainerTitle">SYLLABUS:
  <div class="DownloadThis"></div>
  <div class="ViewThis"></div>
  <div class="showHint"></div>
</div>
<div class="ContainerTitle">NOTE:
  <div class="DownloadThis"></div>
  <div class="ViewThis"></div>
  <p class="showHint"></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It isn't working because `.showHint` is NOT a child of `.DownloadThis` or `.ViewThis`.

Using the tilde (general sibling) selector, this will then select the next (and all) `.showHint` elements within the scope of `.ContainerTitle`.

```
.ViewThis:hover ~ .showHint:after {
  content: '*Hint: View Online';
}
.DownloadThis:hover ~ .showHint:after {
  content: '*Hint: Download';
}
```

Check out my [demo](http://codepen.io/alexmccabe/pen/yOjGKQ)